# JSON decoder 2 get variables

Tags: php, json

how can i get this 2 variables? The $ingredients must get real price from $price, it must get name and price for example TV is amount 3 and price is 20, so it's 60.
Here is code.

```
$ingredients = [
           ['name' => 'TV',                    'amount' => 3],
           ['name' => 'LAPTOP',                   'amount' => 2],
           ['name' => 'HAREM',                'amount' => 2],
           ['name' => 'OIL', 'amount' => 1],
           ['name' => 'Windows',                  'amount' => 1],
           ['name' => 'Something',                  'amount' => 1]
       ];

$prices = [
           'TV'                    => 20,
           'LAPTOP'                   => 20,
           'HAREM'                => 25,
           'OIL' => 20,
           'Windows'                  => 25,
           'Something'                  => 35
       ];
```

Comment: It is a very easy task. Why don’t you show some effort and post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Did you try anything please share ?

Comment: I guess you tried but don't know the proper way to ask here. Please read about how to ask here , for now [check this solution](https://eval.in/973329)

Answer (score 0):

With array_column you get all the 'name' from the array.
This 'name' array can then be searched with array_search to get the key where 'item' is.
Array_search returns false if not found, keep that in mind. 'false' == 0 in PHP.

```
$name = array_column($ingredients,"name");
Foreach($prices as $item => $price){
    $find = array_search($item, $name);
    If($find !== false) $res[$item] = $price * $ingredients[$find]['amount'];
}

Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/oHCCN